# How to create a calendar event in android emulator.

Tags: android, events, calendar, android-calendar, android-syncadapter

I am trying to add calendar events to my custom account..

I have successfully created a calendar event using following code,

```
    private static long addCalendar(Account account) throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException {


Uri calenderUri = Calendars.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name).appendQueryParameter(
Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type).build();
Cursor c1 = mContentResolver.query(calenderUri, new String[] { BaseColumns._ID }, null,    null, null);
if (c1.moveToNext()) {
return c1.getLong(0);
} else {
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

 ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Calendars.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
.appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
.appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name)
.appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type)

.build()
);
builder.withValue(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
builder.withValue(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
builder.withValue(Calendars.NAME, "com.example.karthi");
builder.withValue(Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, "com.example.karthi");
builder.withValue(Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, 0xD51007);
builder.withValue(Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_READ);
builder.withValue(Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, account.name);
builder.withValue(Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
builder.withValue(Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
operationList.add(builder.build());
try {
mContentResolver.applyBatch(CalendarContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
return -1;
}
return addCalendar(account);
}
}
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public static void addEvent(Long id,Account account,String sid,String eventName,String s_date,String duration,String responsible) throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException, ParseException{




        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        Date begin_date = format.parse(String.valueOf(s_date));
       long beginDate = begin_date.getTime();
        long endDate = beginDate + (Double.valueOf(duration).intValue() * HOUR);

     //Insert a new event

            Log.d("add event"+calendarID,"area");
            Log.d("event area","calendar id="+id);
            TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

            ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Events.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name)
                    .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type)
                    .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
                    .build()
                    ); 
            builder.withValue(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, id);
            builder.withValue(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, beginDate);
            builder.withValue(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endDate);

            builder.withValue(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
            builder.withValue(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, eventName);
            operationList.add(builder.build());
            mContentResolver.applyBatch(CalendarContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);

               ContentProviderResult[] res = mContentResolver.applyBatch(CalendarContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);

                Uri myContactUri = res[0].uri;
                int lastSlash = myContactUri.toString().lastIndexOf("/");
                int length = myContactUri.toString().length();
                String event_id =(String) myContactUri.toString().subSequence(lastSlash+1, length);

                s_date=String.valueOf(beginDate);
               String  e_date=String.valueOf(endDate);
            DBAdapter.addEventsData(sid, eventName, s_date, e_date, responsible, event_id);


}
```

My account show in **settings -> Calendars to display** area...
above code also create an event for my custom account.. This code work fine.

But I want to add a event in android emulator it give following error,
[image]

I also try Add account option. If I press **Add account** it allow to create my custom account.

and again try to create an event from android emulator. again it show **No calendars** message.. any help or commands welcome...

**Note: I don`t want programatically add events,It already created from above code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Its my mistake. I give access level only *READ*.

```
builder.withValue(Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL,Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_READ);
```

after change this line to,

```
builder.withValue(Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL,Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
```

Now its working fine.